# Pandas Panel to DataFrame indexing

Tags: python, pandas, panel, hierarchical-data, multi-index

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

pdata = pd.Panel(dict((stk, web.get_data_yahoo(stk, '1/1/2009', '6/1/2012')) 
                      for stk in ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT']))
pdata

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 6 (items) x 861 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: Open to Volume
Major_axis axis: 2009-01-02 00:00:00 to 2012-06-01 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: AAPL to MSFT

                        AAPL        GOOG        MSFT
Date         minor          
2009-01-02   Open       12.268572   153.302917  19.530001
             High       13.005714   159.870193  20.400000
             Low        12.165714   151.762924  19.370001
             Close      12.964286   159.621811  20.330000
             Adj Close  11.621618   159.621811  16.140903
```

Normally the following method would give me what I need:

```
pdata = pdata.swapaxes('items', 'minor')
```

And I get the following warning:

```
Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
The recommended way to represent these types of 3-dimensional data are 
with a MultiIndex on a DataFrame, via the Panel.to_frame() method
```

My objective is to have a Data Frame in the form of a Panel, using the date and stock ticker as Mayor and Minor row indices, and the Open price, etc as the columns as this:

```
              minor   Open       High        Low         Close       Adj Close
Date
2009-01-02    AAPL    12.268572  19.530001   12.165714   12.964286   11.621618    
              GOOG    153.302917 ...         ...         ...         ...
              MSFT    19.530001  ...         ...         ...         ...
```

I did convert the Panel object into a DataFrame and tried to use the pivot_table or set_index methods but I can't get the stock tickers to be the inner row index. When I use the swapaxes method on the DF, the Date is also swaped to the columns. Is there any easy way I can get the format I need?

Comment: I cannot run your code on the latest version of these packages.

Comment: @coldspeed Sometimes the web.get_data_yahoo command doesn't work and one has to run it 2-3 times to make it work. Is the error you're getting from that command?

Comment: Yes. `RemoteDataError`. Ah, running it the 4th time made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`unstack` + `swaplevel` + `sort_index`

```
pdata.to_frame().unstack(0).T\
      .swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index(level=[0]).head(6)

minor                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
Date                                                                          
2009-01-02 AAPL   12.268572   13.005714   12.165714   12.964286   11.621618   
           GOOG  153.302917  159.870193  151.762924  159.621811  159.621811   
           MSFT   19.530001   20.400000   19.370001   20.330000   16.140903   
2009-01-05 AAPL   13.310000   13.740000   13.244286   13.511429   12.112095   
           GOOG  159.462845  164.549759  156.482239  162.965073  162.965073   
           MSFT   20.200001   20.670000   20.059999   20.520000   16.291746   

minor                 Volume  
Date                          
2009-01-02 AAPL  186503800.0  
           GOOG    7267900.0  
           MSFT   50084000.0  
2009-01-05 AAPL  295402100.0  
           GOOG    9841400.0  
           MSFT   61475200.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Wen's wonderful `stack` equivalent.

```
pdata.to_frame().stack().unstack(-2).head(6)

minor                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
Date                                                                          
2009-01-02 AAPL   12.268572   13.005714   12.165714   12.964286   11.621618   
           GOOG  153.302917  159.870193  151.762924  159.621811  159.621811   
           MSFT   19.530001   20.400000   19.370001   20.330000   16.140903   
2009-01-05 AAPL   13.310000   13.740000   13.244286   13.511429   12.112095   
           GOOG  159.462845  164.549759  156.482239  162.965073  162.965073   
           MSFT   20.200001   20.670000   20.059999   20.520000   16.291746   

minor                 Volume  
Date                          
2009-01-02 AAPL  186503800.0  
           GOOG    7267900.0  
           MSFT   50084000.0  
2009-01-05 AAPL  295402100.0  
           GOOG    9841400.0  
           MSFT   61475200.0
```

Comment: Nice solution ! :)

Comment: @user280809 ok :-)

Comment: @Wen I was so sure that there was a stack equivalent, but you nailed it! Wanna write an answer?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nope , you can add to yours my friend ~let us make this site clear  and straightforward to the answer :-)